# ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-i386 Installation as dual boot on ProBook 4430s

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, system-installation

I have Windows 7 already installed, and now I'm trying to install Ubuntu alongside it.

During installation I faced the following problems:

1. The option of **Install Ubuntu alongside Windows** was not available.
2. In the option **Something else** the unallocated space or free space was shown. Also it doesn't show the logical partitions but shows it under extended partition sd4.

It showed partitions sda1 to sda4 of which sda1 and sda2 are obviously system and bootloader partitions. sd3 is I think my HP_recovery drive and sd4 is the extended drive of 300GB. My extended partition has 2 logical partitions D and H. I unallocated 70GB of space by disk management from drive H.

Correct me if I am wrong, but I think problem 1 is because of the fact that I already have 4 primary partitions. I am also aware that Ubuntu can be installed in a logical partition. So my question is: can I install Ubuntu without formatting my whole extended partition, and is there any way to see the logical partitions in the table obtained after clicking **Something else**?

[image]

Comment: Can you open GParted from a LiveUSB and add a screenshot of that?

Comment: All your partitions are Dynamic. Can you convert them back to basic? The output of `sudo fdisk -l` would also be useful so please add it to your question.